# ReactJS and Express with Axios returning 404 Error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios

I have a Node/Express server running on the back end, and a react front end, and am trying to make the simplest API - yet no matter what I do I seem to be getting an error 404 in the post request. I've tried adding a proxy into package.json, removing the proxy and including the port in the address i..e http://localhost:5000/createaccount, including the proxy to http://localhost:5000 and just using '/createaccount' in the post request. I've tried various things with CORS and headers, nothing seems to be working.

When I go to http://localhost:5000/createaccount in my browser separately, it does successfully log "hello world" so I know the server running. I'm also aware for now nothing is actually being done with the sent data, just trying to actually establish a connection for now! I've also tried uncommenting/commenting out most things within the fetch request to no avail.

Server.js code:

```
// server.js

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const PORT = 5000;
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/createaccount", (req, res) => {
  console.log("test");
  res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", ["*"]);
  res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.append("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.send("testComplete");
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on Port: ", PORT);
});
```

CreateAccountjs code:

```
// Create.js

import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Button, FormGroup, FormControl, FormLabel } from "react-bootstrap";

export default class CreateAccount extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.id]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    };
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/createaccount", {
      method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      mode: "cors", // no-cors, cors, *same-origin
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
        // "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      redirect: "follow", // manual, *follow, error
      referrer: "no-referrer", // no-referrer, *client
      body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
    }).then(res => console.log(res));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="CreateAccount">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <FormGroup controlId="email">
            <FormLabel>Email</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              type="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <FormGroup controlId="password">
            <FormLabel>Password</FormLabel>
            <FormControl
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
              type="password"
            />
          </FormGroup>
          <Button type="submit">Sign up!</Button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I see that you have 2 port http://localhost:5000/createaccount and https://localhost:5000/createaccount ?

Comment: What do you mean sorry?

Comment: I see that you have 2 port 1 http and 1 https ? Is this a typo or correct ?

Comment: Apologies, typo yes, when accessing in the browser I actually used http://

Comment: your client is making a POST request but your server accepts GET request. you should change `app.get("/createaccount", (req, res) => {` to `app.post("/createaccount", (req, res) => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You getting 404 because you didnt create a POST routing in node server

So you should have this to place in your code

```
app.post("/createaccount", (req, res) => {

});
```

Please let me know if i'm correct or not

Comment: apologies, I totally forgot to reply! Thanks so much, it did work :)